# How decrease flyway migration

Tags: java, flyway

I have more 200 migration of flyway at the moment on prod project. It's problem for my tests, because they run long time. Is there a right way for decrease count migration files? Maybe best way begin of blank page? Data is very critical

I've no idea at the moment

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is the baseline command. This rolls up all the migrations so that only new migrations are used. [You can read about it here](https://documentation.red-gate.com/fd/baseline-184127456.html).